# Languages disappearing in VS 2019

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2019

I am brand new to asking questions in SO and I do not really know if this question is meant to be asked here but here i am asking anyways.

I will cut to the chase now.

I am using VS 2019 Community and whenever I install for example .NET for C# development , my C++ disappears and I need to reinstall the whole Desktop Development with C++ package and when that gets done , the .NET development package disappears and needs to be reinstalled to be used again.

Does anyone have an idea on why that happens and how it can be fixed?

Comment: In the installer you have to select what you want to install/uninstall. So what did you check there? Anyway: why the Java- and Python-tags?

Comment: run the installer, check all languages you want, install.  What do you get then?

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. RUn your installer and select modify if you've already got it installed.

You'll arrive at a screen like this (this uses my VS 2019 Preview installation which doesn't have a lot selected.)

[image: Language and feature selection page on Visual Studio installer.]

When you have arrived at this page, select the workload you want, in this case "Desktop Development with C++". It will show you how much space will be required. On the right, you'll see it show you the details of what it will install, and you can add/remove any specific SDK versions that you may want right there.

The space required will update to reflect your changes and then once you're done. In this case, I selected Windows SDK version 17763 (I only had one other selected on this device).

[image: After selecting new workload for installation.]

After this you'll have everything you had before, and the new workload that you have just installed.